# Grails User&password protect to a URL

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I want to add the http://grails.org/plugin/console plugin to my production web, but the problem is the security of it.
Is there any simple plugin that only needs user&password, to avoid using the extensive configuration that needs  Spring Security Core or Shiro.

Thanks

Comment: While security isn't something that you can do simply, well correctly and simply, and using the Spring security plugin would be the most secure way of doing this, you do have options such as writing your own Grails filter and implementing your own security checks. Take a look at the docs, they have a very simple example if you read it carefully: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Security and Shiro plugins have large feature sets but do not require "extensive configuration". To use the Spring Security plugin, you just need to

1. install it (add a dependency in BuildConfig like any plugin) and run `grails compile` to resolve it
2. Run the `s2-quickstart` plugin as described in the docs to create your domain classes
3. Create one or more roles (e.g. "ROLE_ADMIN") and a user (BootStrap.groovy is a good place for this)
4. Add rules guarding that URL; add these two lines to the `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules` list in Config.groovy `'/console': ['ROLE_ADMIN']` and `'/console/**': 'ROLE_ADMIN']`